# Run javascript from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, code-behind

I know that there are a lot of question like this. I tried a lot them, but still cant make it working.

I have: `RadAjaxManager`, `RadAjaxPanel`, `RadScriptBlock`

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" 
         DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
         <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="onRequestStart" />
             <AjaxSettings>
                  <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="AjaxPanel">
                      <UpdatedControls>
                          <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="AjaxPanel"/>
                       </UpdatedControls>
                   </telerik:AjaxSetting>
              </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="AjaxPanel" Wrap="True" CssClass="PanelAjax">
         <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cbLanguage" Width="115px" 
             AutoPostBack="True"Sort="Ascending" EmptyMessage="Choose language" 
             DataValueField="id" DataTextField="languageName"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
          </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
      <script>
          function MyFunction(){
                  alert('asdasd');
          }
      </script>
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
</asp:Content>
```

In `Master Page` I have:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

I want to run MyFunction() on `combo box selected index change`.

I have already tried:

```
protected void cbLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "myKey", "MyFunction();");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "testOne", "MyFunction();", true);
}
```

Also i tried just to fire alert directly:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "alert", "alert('asd');", false);

RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(@"radalert('Welcome to RadWindow <b>Prometheus</b>!', 330, 210);");

string treeScript = "<script language='javascript'>alert('asd');</script>";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", treeScript);

RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(@"alert('Welcome');");
```

Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

There are no errors.
Just javascript code is not executed. I dont have `alert()` window on my screen.

Comment: Why is there `1:` and `2:` in front of the lines in your code behind function?

Comment: just to enumerate what I have already tried. there are no '1:' and '2:' in the code

Comment: You should remove that from your code snippet. It is very misleading.

Comment: Btw, you did not mention, what is actually not working with your script. Do you have an error on compile time, on runtime? Do you get a JavaScript error? Does your JavaScript appear in the source code at all? etc. etc.

Comment: No errors, just alert() pop-up does not appear

Comment: But the JavaScript does appear in your source code?

Comment: Good question, actually it does not.

For example
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('asd');", false);`

After `cbLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged` is executed there is no `alert('asd');` in page source html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a syntax error in your javascript! You have a typo in your declaration.

You wrote:

```
  <script>
      fuction MyFunction(){
              alert('asdasd');
      }
  </script>
```

But it has to be:

```
  <script>
      function MyFunction(){
              alert('asdasd');
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: It's just here, i did not copy-paste and typed with error.
there is everything ok in the code:
 `function MyFunction() { alert("it works!");}`

Comment: It's some sort of annoying tekerik magic.

I tried 'RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(@"MyFunction();");'
previously but it did not work. And now it works.

Thank you for your help)

Comment: @makambi: Maybe you missed a character some where or I don´t know. Glad it works now! :)